# How can I prevent text messages going to my Mac?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, messages

I have just bought a MacBook Pro and all my text messages are coming through to it before coming through to my phone.

I don't want this. I have followed help tips by opening Messages app but can't find the iMessage preferences to change it as advised by other people.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Messages.app from the Applications folder, or Spotlight (⌘-space).
2. Open the Preferences window from Messages → Preferences or press ⌘,

   [image]
3. Select the Accounts tab.

   [image]
4. Select your iCloud account and uncheck the Enable this account option.

   [image]